# How could I use the same tslint.json in submodules, too?

Tags: json, angular, configuration, lint, tslint

A big Angular 5 project is given with several submodules (from different repositories) and I couldn't specify the path to neither node_modules/codelyzer nor tslint-base.json from a submodule's tslint.json.

The tree is something like this:

```
tslint-base.json
node_modules
...
modules
  submod1
    tslint.json
    components
    ...
  submod2
    tslint.json
    components
    ...
```

*tslint-base.json:*

```
{
    "rulesDirectory": [
        "node_modules/codelyzer"
    ],
    "rules": {
      ...
    }
}
```

Of course it works well when we open the root of the project with IDE (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate), but we often open it from one of the submodules, not the project root. So IDE does not see the node_modules/codelyzer folder from submodule's tslint.json. I have already tried:

*1. tslint.json*

```
{
    "rulesDirectory": [
        "../../node_modules/codelyzer"
    ]
}
```

*2. tslint.json*

```
{
    "rulesDirectory": [
        "./../../node_modules/codelyzer"
    ]
}
```

*3. tslint.json*

```
{
    "extends": [
        "./../../tslint-base.json"
    ]
}
```

*4. tslint.json*

```
{
    "extends": [
        "../../tslint-base.json"
    ]
}
```

And I also tried these in combinations. But it doesn't work...

What do I wrong?